# pandas finding the indices of a common value between two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this:
df1

```
Date and time   Price1  PrePrice
17.9.2018 9:47  1200.6  1204.8
17.9.2018 9:47  1200.6  1203.8
17.9.2018 9:47  1200.6  1202.1
17.9.2018 9:47  1200.6  1204.8
17.9.2018 9:47  1200.6  1204.8
17.9.2018 9:47  1200.6  1204.8
17.9.2018 9:47  1202.1  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:30 1200.7  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:31 1200.7  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:32 1200.6  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:33 1200.6  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:36 1200.7  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:47 1200.7  1204.8
17.9.2018 23:48 1200.6  1202.1
17.9.2018 23:50 1202.1  1200.9
17.9.2018 23:52 1203.8  1200.8
17.9.2018 23:55 1204.8  1200.7
```

I would like to get the common values between the two columns Price1,PrePrice
like this :`(1204.8; 17.9.2018 9:47; 17.9.2018 23:55)`
It tried this method but it's very slow:

```
c = [(i, j)  for i, x in enumerate(a) for j, y in enumerate(b) if x == y]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want places where they are equal on the same row, this is vanilla Pandas:

```
df1[df1.Price1 == df1.PrePrice]
```

(There are none in your example.)

If you want all shared values you can use set notation:

```
c = set(df1.Price1).intersection(df1.PrePrice)
print(c)
> {1200.7, 1202.1, 1203.8, 1204.8}
```

Given those times, you can filter for `Date and Time` with `Price1`:

```
df1[df1.Price1.isin(c)][['Date and time', 'Price1']]

    Date and time   Price1
6   17.9.2018 9:47      1202.1
7   17.9.2018 23:30     1200.7
8   17.9.2018 23:31     1200.7
11  17.9.2018 23:36     1200.7
12  17.9.2018 23:47     1200.7
14  17.9.2018 23:50     1202.1
15  17.9.2018 23:52     1203.8
16  17.9.2018 23:55     1204.8
```

Comment: I would the result like this:(1204.8; 17.9.2018 9:47; 17.9.2018 23:55), it means the value 1204.8 found in the location 17.9.2018 9:47 and the location 17.9.2018 23:55

Comment: thx,Josh but the piece of code gave mixed locations or indices , its important for me is to get the first location found of the x value and second location of the x value like this(value X: first_position,second_position)

Comment: It's looks promising .l will try it

Comment: Can u please show me how you read the file ithink I have an option missing I think it's how I can deal with time 

Comment: Just replace `Date and Time` with whatever your date/time column is called. I read the file in with `pandas.read_clipboard`, just changing it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Adil/Desktop/test.csv",delimiter=';', decimal=',',parse_dates=["Date and time"],index_col="Date and time") 
finally the above code is working.
but still far from the desired result :(1204.8; 17.9.2018 9:47; 17.9.2018 23:55)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you have a new question, please post it as such rather than as an answer.